# Photon Fock-State to Polarization State connection involving Beam-Splitter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

Suppose we have a BeamSplitter (BS, 50:50) and on one of the input sides we have a single photon, and on another side, we have a vacuum then we get the output as $|\psi \rangle_{out} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|1\rangle_{3}|0\rangle_{4}+ |0\rangle_{3}|1\rangle_{4})$. Where we consider output as 3 and 4 and input as 1 and 2. Clearly, the input is $|1\rangle_{1}|0\rangle_{2}$, and outputs 3 and 4 are connected via 1 and 2 with Electric Field conditions.

Now suppose instead of looking on a fock-basis if we consider polarization basis for the single photon case then the photon state would be $|\psi\rangle_{1} = \alpha|H\rangle + \beta |V\rangle$ and similarly another input is vacuum state then how the output state will look like?

And would be the corresponding unitray matrix for the BS ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the BS is still a 50:50 BS and not a polarizing beamsplitter (PBS), the polarization basis would not have much of an effect. The bases do not change the physical situation. Moreover, polarization represents spin degrees of freedom, which are different from the particle-number degrees of freedom as represented by the Fock basis. Physical photons carry spin degrees of freedom and spatiotemporal degrees of freedom in addition to being represented as Fock states. The unitary matrix for the 50:50 BS only operates on the particle-number degrees of freedom and therefore does not change, apart from the fact that you need to sum over all other degrees of freedom in the definition of the operator.

So, for the scenario with a single-photon having a particular state of polarization entering one port of a 50:50 beam splitter, with vacuum at the other port, the output is the same as before, with the single photons in the superposition having the same state of polarization as the original input photon.